# How do I make my @HostListener work only in the component where I am

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a keyboard shortcut to call the functions I need, but when I press the key even though I'm in a specific component, it calls all of them.
below only the first component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-firstComponent',
  templateUrl: './firstComponent.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./firstComponent.page.scss'],
})

export class FirstComponentPage extends DocumentPage implements DocumentPageInterface {

 

  constructor(
    attendanceService: AttendanceService,
    alertCtrl: AlertController,
    modalCtrL: ModalController,
    private utilService: UtilService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private anamenesePDF: AnamneseService
  ) {
    super(DocumentType.FIRSTCOMPONENT, attendanceService, utilService, alertCtrl, modalCtrL);
  }

@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    switch (event.key) {
      case "F1":
        this.onPrint();
        break;
      case "F2":
        this.onNewDocument();
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

These components are in a supertabs

Pages.HTML

```
<super-tabs-container>
      <super-tab>
        <ion-content>
          <app-firstComponent [attendance]="attendance" [patient]="patient"></app-firstComponent>
        </ion-content>
      </super-tab>

      <super-tab>
        <ion-content>
          <app-historico-pregresso [attendance]="attendance" [patient]="patient"></app-historico-pregresso>
        </ion-content>
      </super-tab>
```

Pages.TS

```
 slideToSuperTab(superTab) {
    switch (superTab) {
      case AttendancePages.FIRSTCOMPONENT:
        return this.superTabs.selectTab(0);

      case AttendancePages.HISTORICO_PREGRESSO:
        return this.superTabs.selectTab(1);

      case AttendancePages.SINAIS_VITAIS:
        return this.superTabs.selectTab(2);


enum AttendancePages {
  FIRSTPAGE = 'firstPage',
  HISTORICO_PREGRESSO = 'historico_pregresso',
  SINAIS_VITAIS = 'sinais_vitais',
}
```

I put the block of code in one component, but when I slide for another when I keydown "f1" they call onPrint() in every components.